# Debug a Http 405 "Method Not Allowed"

Tags: html, http

A web server is running (on EC2) and I'm testing this simple Html5 login form with a method="post" attribute in two ways:

1. as-is
2. within a larger website

> ```
> <div>
>     <form action="" method="post" >
>         <p/>
>         <input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" >
>         <p/>
>         <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" >
>         <p/>
>         <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Login">
>     </form>
> </div>
> ```

A handler in the Python-based web server includes:

```
username = self.get_argument('username') 
password = self.get_argument('password')
```

The first method works with a Http 200 but the second generates a Http 405 "Method Not Allowed".  Both use the identical handler code on the web server.

I cannot find where the problem is.  What is the best way to debug this?

Comment: More information on the Python-based web server, what is it? What's different between 1 and 2 in terms of stack perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the web-server and the order of the parameters/attributes for the Class function handling the Post method.